# Informatica java process utilizing a lot of memory causing high CPU usage

Tags: informatica

I have Informatica 9.5 installed on a Windows 2008 server.  In Task Manager, I've noticed java.exe *32 is consuming a lot of memory on the Informatica server.  Can someone tell me what this process is used for?  What could be the cause for the high memory?  Is there a fix?

Thank you.

Comment: Normally java uses lots of memory and this is why you need a server with lots of memory to host informatica. What is your configurations of server ? Also how do you know the java.exe belongs to informatica?

Comment: @KoushikRoy, thanks for responding.  What do you mean by configurations of server?  Also, I'm not sure if the java.exe belongs to Informatica.  I just know it's utilizing high cpu and memory.

Comment: by config i mean - how many CPUs , how much RAM etc.? java can be tied to lots of process. what else you have in this server.  You can check from running process - what services are tied to them.

Comment: 1 CPU, 4 GB RAM, 64 bit OS.  Processes running, infasvcs.exe, Java.exe, pmserver.exe, pmrepagent.exe, pmdtm.exe and default windows processes.  The infasvcs.exe process is the only process tied to a service which is Informatica 9.5.

Comment: Is it advised to stop java process?  Do you know if it will impact Informatica?

Comment: I think your system need to be beefed up to minimum 2CPU. Here is infa recommended values.
Domain with all Data Quality, Data Services, and
PowerCenter services running on one node - 4 CPU 8 GB 20 GB
Domain with all PowerCenter services running on one node - 2 CPU 4 GB 4 GB
Now, java process i think is related to infa you can check too - right click on java then check which service is tied to this.